# PHP GD thumbnail generation image pixels distorted

Tags: php, image-processing, gd, thumbnails

I've php script to generate thumbnails on images upload, using PHP GD Library.

The height of the thumbnail is fixed ( in this case its **240px**), and its width will be calculated according to original image's aspect ratio.
ex.

```
$new_height = $thumbHeight;
$new_width = intval($thumbHeight * $width / $height);
```

but in some images the output thumbnail image having pixels distorted. Below images  addresses my question clearly.

[image: Exaple Image]

After generating thumbnail the output image (**Left**), but i want the output image as it is in **Right**

My Code :

```
$file = "pic.jpg";
$thumbHeight = 240;
$progressive = false;

    $img;
    if(preg_match('/[.](jpg)$/', $file)) {
        $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
    } else if (preg_match('/[.](gif)$/', $file)) {
        $img = imagecreatefromgif($file);
    } else if (preg_match('/[.](png)$/', $file)) {
        $img = imagecreatefrompng($file);
    } else  if(preg_match('/[.](jpeg)$/', $file)) {
        $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
    }

$arr_image_details = getimagesize($file);
$width = $arr_image_details[0]; // width of input image
$height = $arr_image_details[1]; // height of input image

$new_height = $thumbHeight;    // new thumbnail height 
$new_width = intval($thumbHeight * $width / $height);  // new thumbnail width


$tmp_img = imagecreatetruecolor( $new_width, $new_height );
imagecopyresized( $tmp_img, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height );
if($progressive) imageinterlace($tmp_img, 1); 
imagejpeg( $tmp_img, "lag-$file",100 ); 

imagedestroy($img);
imagedestroy($tmp_img);
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `imagecopyresampled` instead of `imagecopyresized` ?

Comment: no i have'nt tried .. but is `imagecopyresized` differs.. ?

Comment: It often makes the result is better and images are smoother than using `imagecopyresized`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `imagecopyresampled()` function instead of `imagecopyresized()` often makes the rendered image smoother, so in this case probably it will be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Used `imagecopyresampled` instead of `imagecopyresized` done the trick ..

Reason :

[`imagecopyresized`](http://www.php.net/imagecopyresized) will copy and scale and image. This uses a fairly primitive algorithm that tends to yield more pixelated results.

[`imagecopyresampled`](http://www.php.net/imagecopyresampled) will copy and scale and image, it uses a smoothing and pixel interpolating algorithm that will generally yield much better results then imagecopyresized at the cost of a little cpu usage.